# Ошибка при запуске проекта на React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

Создал новый реакт проект черех npx create-react-app. И вроде бы всё хорошо, но при запуске локально проекта через среду разработки (VS Code или webStorm) каждый раз вылазит ошибка типа:
`Failed to load config "airbnb" to extend from. Referenced from: C:\Users\....\package.json`.
Советы, которые дают на англоязычном SO, типа удалить и заново поставить node_modules или обновить Eslint как-то не помогли. Ошибка не уходит. Что интересно, это началось неделю назад. Более ранние проекты работают без этой ошибки.
Подскажите, может сталкивался кто-то? И как фиксили?

package.json:

```
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-markdown": "^2.2.1",
    "node-modules": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "plugin:flowtype/recommended",
      "airbnb",
      "prettier",
      "prettier/react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "prettier",
      "flowtype"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.5",
    "eslint": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.50.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```